# Uncaught Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node web3.min.js:1 http://localhost:8545

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp

**Hi, I am doing a sample project on Ethereum where 2 fields ( Emp name, Emp Id) will be taken from the UI and set those values using a smart contract and show the values back to UI. Getting below 2 errors.Please help me out to solve this.

1. > Failed to load http://localhost:8545/: Response to preflight request
   >   doesn't pass access control check: The value of the
   >   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the
   >   wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin
   >   'null' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of
   >   requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the
   >   withCredentials attribute. t.send @ web3.min.js:1
2. > Uncaught Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node
   >   http://localhost:8545.
   >       at Object.InvalidConnection (web3.min.js:1)
   >       at t.send (web3.min.js:1)
   >       at n.send (web3.min.js:1)
   >       at l.accounts (web3.min.js:1)
   >       at index.html:41 InvalidConnection @ web3.min.js:1 t.send @ web3.min.js:1 n.send @ web3.min.js:1 (anonymous) @ web3.min.js:1
   >   (anonymous) @ index.html:41

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow remote connections to ethereum node. I am assuming you are trying to connect to remote ethereum node. To allow ethereum node a connection requests from other devices on which `geth` is not running you'll need to use `--rpcaddr` and `--rpccorsdomain` flags to allow external RPC connections.

Use the following command for initiating `geth`

```
geth --datadir "path to data directory" --networkid 9876 --rpcport "8545" --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpccorsdomain "*"
```

Comment: path to data directory means?

Comment: --datadir to specify the directory for private ethereum blockchain. This is good practice when you are interacting with different chains.